# Basic "manga reader"-like carousel of images

Tags: javascript, html, image, carousel

I have several pages of a manga in .png format, around 300, and I would like to set up a section on my website so that users can read the manga, browsing through the pages using two arrows ("next page" and "previous page"). I don't care about animations between pages. The perfect example of what I want to achieve is MangaFox (not the whole website, just the window where you can read the manga).

The basic setting is: a 300px wide menu with the chapters list on the left, and manga pages appearing to the right. Either in the menu or below where the manga page img, two arrows let you go to the previous or next page.

I thought about using iframes: links to HTML pages containing each manga page would target the iframe and appear in it. However, this requires me to ceate an HTML page for each page, and set the links to the previous and next page manually. I would have 300 html pages, so this would be too heavy and time consuming.
I also tried linking the chapters list directly to the .png files, but the images are not styled as I would like (at least in Chrome, they don't appear in the center of the page, but rather in the upper left corner) and I would still have to set the previous and next arrows link manually.

Whai I dream of is:
- there's a list of the .png files, that sets a fixed order for the pages;
- a dropdown list in the left menu can point directly to a certain page in the list;
- the previous and next arrows recognize which image is being shown, and a click on the arrows skips to the next or previous item on the list. If there's no page before the current one, the "previous" arrow disappears; same for the "next" arrow in case the item is the last on the list.

Maybe there's a way simpler way to do it I didn't think of, but I can't find it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

(P.S.: I'm not using WordPress, just plain HTML, CSS and PHP)

Comment: You could try something like this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp. More information about bootstrap is available here http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: With that many images, try making just a basic page with Owl Carousel, slick for jQuery, or the lazy loading bootstrap carousel (recommended by Izaaz). You don't really need to have multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way I can think of doing this:

Left arrow

```
<a id="leftArrow" href="#{n-1}"></a>
```

Right arrow

```
<a id="rightArrow" href="#{n+1}"></a>
```

Set up [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) function that reads `location.hash` and sets the `src` attribute of the `img` element utilizing an array of pages you've defined somewhere:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    var img = document.query('img');
    var left = document.query('#leftArrow');
    var right = document.query('#rightArrow');
    var pageNumber = parseInt(location.hash);
    //put some error handling here for edge cases, then...
    img.src = imagesArray[pageNumber];
    left.href = '#' + (pageNumber - 1);
    right.href = '#' + (pageNumber + 1);
};
```

The page links in your side menu would have `href="#{page number}"` and would trigger the `onhashchange` function when clicked, updating the image and the arrows.

Hope this helps.